# Ignite persistent. Schema tables disappeared sometimes

Tags: ignite, nlpcraft

I have problems with the database based on ignite.
Sometimes (I can't catch exact situation) after restart server/os etc, the system started with empty schema (all created tables disappeared)

1. Environment:

   - Ignite 2.7, 2.7.5
   - OS - macOS 10.14.5
   - java 1.8.0_121, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
   - it's single node.
2. jdbc

   jdbc {
       # Ignite JDBC URL and driver.
       url = "jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/nlpcraft"
       driver = org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver
       # username =
       # password =
   }
3. ignite.xml:

   ```
       <property name="sqlSchemas">
           <list>
               <value>nlpcraft</value>
           </list>
       </property>

       <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
               <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                   <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                       <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                   </bean>
               </property>
           </bean>
       </property>
       ......
   ```

How can I resolve it?
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide node logs from the run where tables disappear?

Comment: which log level should be used for "org.apache.ignite"?

Comment: `INFO` should be sufficient!

Comment: Is it possible that you've lost your persistence directory somehow? Maybe you mount a disk via network (something like NAS) or run your node as a docker image without proper file system mappings?

Comment: No, it is usual SSD, also the problem is repeatable on different computers with same environments.

Comment: It reminds me of a case when a path to the files on disk is changed upon restarts. Ignite had that issue before and it was already addressed. Probably something similar bubbled up.

Please scroll down to the bottom of this section that explains how the path is set:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store#section-usage

Can you see the files in your "work" directory? Does anything change if you set consistentId explicitly?

Comment: Resolved. Thank you for your help!
1) my Ignite log level was ERROR, so I skipped useful warning
Persistence store directory is in the temp directory and may be cleaned...
 (see DataStorageConfiguration#walPath, #walArchivePath, #storagePath properties)...
2) Now I have configured these 3 properties as absolute paths and hope it is solution (relative paths don't work, I have same WARN message)
I agree that it was not best idea to turn off Ignite logs, but I think better to include such important info  to DataStorageConfiguration javadoc and comments of configuration examples.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the files were written to a temporary folder of the file system and removed upon nodes restart. We updated [Ignite documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store#section-persistence-path-management):

- Ensure that WARN logging level is not disabled for Ignite. You will
  see a warning if the persistence files are written to the temporary directory.
- Change the location of all persistence files using the APIs of
  `DataStorageConfiguration` such as `setStoragePath(...)`, `setWalPath(...)` and `setWalArchivePath(...)`.

Thanks for helping to pinpoint the issue. We'll go ahead and see how Ignite can handle this automatically.

Comment: Why not use the current user's home folder and have .ignite folder there? Why do we use self-cleaned temp folders to begin with?

Comment: Have no idea why `temp` is not filtered out by default. It will be reconsidered in the upcoming versions.